# Getting all models that have HABTM association to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have three models:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stuffs
end

class Stuff < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_and_belongs_to_many :vehicles
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stuffs
end
```

And I need something like that:

```
some_vehicle.stuffs.categories
```

and it should return a list of `categories` for all `stuffs` that `some_vehicle` has.
How can I get it?
Or maybe it should be some custom SQL query?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.